# Mockito specific matchers like anyString() don't seem to work with overloaded methods?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I'm attempting to write a unit test for a class with JUnit and Mockito and in my testing, I've found that a method that I'm trying to stub is actually overloaded and has two definitions, one with 3 strings as an arg and returns an object, another with four strings and returns a list of the aforementioned object. I'm curious as to why matchers such as anyString() don't seem to successfully stub the method, while any() does.

Is there any way I can get more specific matchers to work, or am I stuck with using any() for overloaded methods?

An example of what I mean:

```
public String testedMethod(String s) {
    //I want to mock this
    return classObject.method(String first, String second, String third);
}
```

```
public class classObject {
    public String method(String first, String second, String third) {
        return "3 args";
    }

    public List<String> method(String first, String second, String third, String fourth) {
        ArrayList<String> returned = new ArrayList<>();
        returned.add("4 args");
        return returned;
    }
}
```

```
@Test
public void testClassMethod() {
    //this doesn't work
    //Mockito.when(classObject).method(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn("successful stub");

    //this does work
    Mockito.when(classObject).method(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()).thenReturn("successful stub");

    //only passes with the second mock
    Assert.assertEquals("successful stub", testedClass.testedMethod("a string"));
}
```

Comment: Do you care to explain more in detail what you mean with "doesn't seem to successfully stub the method" and share some code examples?

Comment: Suppose I have Method A that I want to stub, but shares the same method name with Method B, but each have differing amounts of arguments. I want to stub Method A in the method that I'm testing, so i can ignore its functionality. When I use anyString() as an argument matcher, Method A is still executed as normal, as if it wasn't stubbed at all. However, using any() does cause the stubbing to succeed and returns the value I specified in Mockito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mockito.anyString()` does not match `null` values, because `null` is not an instance of  `String`.

You're most likely not able to mock the method when replacing `any()` with `anyString()` simply because one of the method arguments is actually `null` rather than a `String`.

More information on the topic: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/185

Comment: Thanks! This fixed everything!

Comment: Glad to hear that, have a nice day :)